# wso2is custom authenticationendpoint, redirect page not used

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am developing saml sso using wso2is. I customized the authentication endpoint according the blog post below [1](http://dulanja.blogspot.sk/2014/01/wso2-is-samlsso-customizing-login-page.html). Basically I just deployed a war on my server and configured application-authenticators.xml to use it:

```
<Authenticators>
<Authenticator name="BasicAuthenticator" disabled="false" factor="1">
    <!-- <Status value="10" loginPage="/authenticationendpoint/login.do" /> -->
    <Status value="10" loginPage="https://servlet.example.com/customlogin/login.do" /> 
</Authenticator>
</Authenticators>
```

login is working fine, my custom login-page sends a form to "https://servlet.example.com/idp/commonauth" which redirects me to my sp. but I also want to customize the redirect-page after the login. in the custom endpoint there is a file named 'samlsso_redirect.jsp' which looks like it should do the work but its contents are ignored.

strangely 'samlsso_redirect.jsp' the the bundled authentication endpoint is also ignored.

I have also downloaded the sources of wso2is and found org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet hard codes the redirect message in the sendResponse() method.

Does somebody know how it is working and what I am missing here? How can I customize the redirect message?

http://dulanja.blogspot.sk/2014/01/wso2-is-samlsso-customizing-login-page.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WSO2IS 5.0.0 version or higher version,  You can simplify edit html file which can be found at `IS_HOME\repository\resources\security\sso_redirect.html`

Following applies to WSO2IS 4.6.0 and older versions

It seems to be that redirect page is can not be customized by using some extension. Please see this [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2034)

However You can do as following if you want to customize it in 4.6.0...

1. svn checkout https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml/4.2.2
2. In src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/saml/servlet/SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java you have to modify the HTML getting printed in sendResponse() method.
3. Build the component using maven and place as a patch in wso2is-4.6.0/repository/components/patches.  Copy jar file into any patch directory
4. Restart the server

note : The built jar name appears as: org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml-4.2.2.jar. Make sure to rename it to org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml_4.2.2.jar (notice that the dash is replaced by an underscore) before placing in the patch folder.

Comment: works fine! just wanted to note that it is really strange to have the file with the suggestive name 'samlsso_redirect.jsp' ignored and a hardcoded html-string with the SAME content used instead!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IS 5.0 then you need to modify this page:
`IS_HOME\repository\resources\security\sso_redirect.html`