# Customize samlsso_redirect.jsp in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am looking to customize `samslsso_redirect.jsp` for WSO2 IS v5.0.0
The solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364652/wso2is-custom-authenticationendpoint-redirect-page-not-used) is not a viable one for me since my JSP changes are enormous.

As per this [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2034) a fix for this issue is available in 5.0.0-GA.

However, I am still not able to customize this page and the HTML is being rendered from `SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java`

Is there a direct way to customize this JSP like we can do for `login.jsp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IS 5.0 then you need to modify this page: `IS_HOME\repository\resources\security\sso_redirect.html`